# Reading two ints from an array as a long

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, microcontroller

I am working on a microcontroller project in which I have an array of unsigned ints that comes in from a communications interface. These are accessed through define macros for convenience.

I need to get sent some unsigned long values, instead of having to process two values from the comms register and shift them into a secondary long register, is it safe for me to use pointers and read two values out of the array at once.

I am interested in doing this as processing resources on the controller are quite limited. Is this safe, will array values always be contiguous in memory?

Example code

```
...

unsigned int comms[MAX_ADDRESS];

...

#define FOO             comms[0]
#define BAR             comms[1]
#define VAL_1           comms[2]
#define VAL_1_EXT       (*(unsigned long*)(&comms[2])) // Use pointer trickery to read a long
#define VAL_2           comms[4]
#define VAL_2_EXT       (*(unsigned long*)(&comms[4]))

...
```

Not sure if it is relevant but it is a chip from the MSP430 family from TI, compiler version `TI 4.3.3`

Comment: Are the sender and receiver of the unsigned longs of the same endian-ness?

Comment: Looks like the microcontroller is little endian http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430_CPU
The other end is a C# application on a PC where the processing power can be afforded to shift bits around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "safe."  It's absolutely unsafe in the sense that the C Standard says nothing about what will happen because you are aliasing types with pointer casts.  This is non-portable.

But non-portable doesn't mean non-functional. If the code is not for production use and you have good control over the development environment, you're likely to do fine with your proposal. The C Standard *does* guarantee that array elements are contiguous.  If the compiler generates code that fetches the two (I'm guessing) 16-bit quantities from the commo registers to correctly form a 32-bit long in one instance, then it is virtually certain that:

- It will do so in all usages.
- Future compiler versions will do the same.

There are no guarantees, but in practice it's a reasonable bet.

To learn whether the code you're getting is correct, compile with `-S` and inspect.  Write a good test to verify.

At any rate you have taken a good approach by isolating the access code in macros (though you should drop the semi-colons at the ends).

The following macro *is* well-defined with respect to the C Standard.

```
#define VAL_1_EXT       (((unsigned long)comms[3] << 16) | (unsigned long)comms[2])
```

If the you wrote

```
unsigned long x = VAL_1_EXT;
```

a good optimizing compiler should generate much the same code with the macro above as with your proposed one.  I guess you're saying it's not a good optimizing compiler.

As pointed out in comments, this macro is not an l-value. You can't assign *to* it.  For that you'll need a separate macro.

```
#define SET_VAL_1_EXT(Val) do { \
  unsigned long x = (unsigned long)Val;
  comms[2] = x; \
  comms[3] = (unsigned)(x >> 16); \
} while (0)
```

Comment: `comms[2]` might not be correctly aligned for `long`

Comment: -1, undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour, it isn't just "non-portable", it's undefined.

Comment: This is a good answer, if I understand it correctly you are saying, anything may happen, but the same anything should always happen, so if I can verify the code, and always use the same compiler I can expect the code to contiune to work.

The semi-colens was a bit of a copy pase goof up from when I encapsulated it in the macro.

I did consider the bit-shift method as listed but was trying to come up with somthing bi-directional if possible.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy he does say that it's undefined but is "virtually certain" to work... (which is true apart from the alignment issue), and he does give a portable alternative. Surely worth +0.8 at least, not -1 :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Undefined behaviour is not "virtually certain" to work, it's undefined.  The compiler can literally do whatever it wants.  If the compiler finds this in a program, it can delete all the code in the program, "optimizing" it to a no op.  If this undefined behaviour is on a branch, the compiler can assume that branch is never taken.  This approach isn't kind of wrong, it's absolutely wrong, especially given that unions exist in the language to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy Yeah and nobody is going to buy such a compiler. We're talking about the real world here. "Undefined" means "Undefined by the C standard", not "impossible to predict what the compiler will do". No compiler is 100% conforming anyway. Unions don't solve this problem either, (the strict aliasing rule still applies).

Comment: @Hugoagogo: That's not what undefined behaviour means.  Undefined behaviour means that the compiler is free to do anything.  Your code has undefined behaviour.  It can do anything.  You shouldn't make assumptions about what it does or will do because it does something particular right now.  It is meaningless code because the C standard does not give it a meaning.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The strict aliasing rule has an explicit exemption for unions: "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members" §6.5.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You want a well-optimizing compiler though, right? Guess what, compiler writers use all those edge-cases to get that level of optimization.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy `int` and `long` are not aggregate or union types. That line does not mean "any type which is in a union", it means a type which *is* a union

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The union-in-question would contain both `int` and `long`.

Comment: @Deduplicator give an example of any compiler ever where the above code doesn't work (other than for alignment reasons). If you can't, then it seems to me that "virtually certain" is an appropriate description.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy The code aliases the memory via lvalues of type `int` and `long` (not of union type)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Even if this has worked on every compiler ever, that's no guarantee that it will continue to work.  This is the very essence of "undefined": The fact that it works, or has worked, is meaningless, there's no guarantee it will continue to work.  The fact that alignment is even a concern should be a major red flag.  Unions, however, deal with alignment for you.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy we are talking about "virtually certain", not "guaranteed".

Comment: @MattMcNabb: How about GCC? Don't have example code handy just now though. And in case of UB, you have to prove that all implementations (past, present and future) guarantee the specific behavior you want, not assume so until proven wrong.

Comment: @Deduplicator no proofs are required for "virtually certain" to hold. There could be  some counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard, you have an aliasing bug, anything may happen.

The compiler is allowed to assume there is no aliasing between 16-bit `int` and 32-bit `long` types, and you might get surprising behavior (without warning) because you break that contract.

Just say no, use bit-shifting to compose your `long` from the two `int`s, and depend on the compiler to optimize that out for you (It should not really use bit-shifting under-the-hood). You might want to look at the assembly to determine whether it fails.

> #### 6.5 Expressions § 7
>
> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:88)
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>   — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>   — a character type.

As `int` and `long` are not compatible, and there is no exception, aliasing them is forbidden.

The more modern (and the better at optimizing) your compiler is, the more likely it is playing loose will bite you.

BTW: Most compilers implement many dialects, and GCC allows disabling of strict aliasing with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. Be sure not just to disable the warning but the actual optimizations.

Comment: Interesting - could you please explain further?

Comment: @LawrenceDol: Added quote

Comment: It can be noted that from practical point of view, adding `-fno-strict-aliasing` to the GCC command line helps to overcome the limitation. On the other hand, this may restrict the compiler's optimization capacity.

Comment: Thanks for the spec refference

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: Yes, should have mentioned that flag. Though I'm not sure how reliably it disables all optimizations which might rely on strict aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this, are confident that `sizeof(int)*2==sizeof(long)` on your platform, and are content with this non-portability (because this assumption is non-portable) you can (and should) use a union to move back and forth between the two types in a defined manner.

```
union {
    int in [2];
    long out;
};
```

You may either store elements of this union type in your array, and write `int`s to `in` and read `long`s from `out`, or you can place `int`s from an `int` array into the union, and the read them out two at a time as a `long`.

Note that if you want more portability, you can use the integer types from [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h):

```
union {
    int32_t in [2];
    int64_t out;
};
```

Then the only platform-dependent behaviours will be:

- How signed integers are represented
- Endianness

Comment: If I understand the standard right, you may only read a member of the union you have previously written, so writing both `int` and reading them back as a single `long` is not allowed. Not really sure about that though.

Comment: This also causes UB for strict aliasing violation (even if you are allowed to read a different member than the one last written, which the standard has always been unclear about)

Comment: It does say "The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is safe, with the following assumptions:

- The sender of this data is sending data as you're expecting. For example, `comms[2]` and `comms[3]` together do actually make up an `unsigned long` value, as you expect.
- The sender's bit order (known as [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) and byte order are what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Per the subsequent comment on the question, the answer is no. My original answer explains why.

---

It depends on the whether you want completely safe and portable code, or are OK with code for a specific architecture, as well as on the endianess and order of the `int`s.

If you are OK with specific code, then...

Arrays in C are always consecutive memory locations and always packed, and a lot of code depends on this.

On a big endian system, if you have `int`s in the order

```
high-int,low-int
```

each `int` is

```
high-byte,low-byte
```

and the bytes in memory are

```
high-int-high,high-int-low,low-int-high,low-int-low
```

which you can then deference using a `(long int*)` cast. But not on a little endian system.

On a little endian system, if you have `int`s in the order

```
low-int,high-int
```

each `int` is

```
low-byte,high-byte
```

the bytes in memory are

```
low-int-low,low-int-high,high-int-low,high-int-high
```

which you can then deference using a `(long int*)` cast. But not on a big endian system.

Comment: As in comment on question the microcontroller is little-endian, I assume the point made in your answer can be reversed i.e. low-int, high-int - low-byte,-high-byte

Comment: That comment wasn't there when I wrote my answer (or at least, when I started it). It's still a legitimate answer, even so.

Answer (score 0):

I believe casting the unsigned int pointer to a unsigned long pointer will work on the MSP430 because the MSP430 is little endian *AND* the MSP430 does not require 4-byte longs to be aligned on 4-byte boundaries.  But don't count on this working on another platform.

And don't expect that you can also cast two consecutive bytes to an unsigned int.  The MSP430 requires that 2-byte words must be aligned on an even address.  So if the first byte happens to be at an odd address then you will get undefined behavior when you cast it to a word.